# Can curly braces in PHP be placed outside the php script tags?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am reading some wordpress code of my company webpages in order to understand them. But, I am seeing that the curly brace is not completed inside a tag. Like in the below code, why is the curly brace in second line not completed in the script tag there itself, but placed in the end?

If this is to continue the loop, why is the script tag closed? Why not to continue in it?

```
while(have_posts())
    { the_post(); ?>
        <?php $postMetas = get_post_meta(get_the_ID()); ?>
        <?php /*echo "<pre>"; print_r($postMetas); die; */?>
        <div class="row top2">
            <div class="overlay">
                <div class="overlay-gradient"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="video">
                <?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wpcf-select-image', true) == 1){ ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wpcf-image', true); ?>" alt="">
                <?php }else{ ?>

                <?php } ?>
            </div>
 <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, curly brackets `{}` signify the start and the end of a code block. That code block has to be complete or you get an `E_FATAL` error on compile.

What's throwing you is that the start and end brackets are in separate `<?php ?>` blocks. This is allowed as long as you match the brackets. As to why you use this, it's so you can place non-PHP code (in this case HTML) around your code block instead of using long `echo` strings.

If this is too confusing, you can always use [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

```
<?php while(have_posts(): ?>
    Your while block code here
<?php endwhile ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Can curly braces in PHP be placed outside the php script tags?

No. If you do not use them within the PHP tags then PHP will interpret them as text.
As such, PHP will return an error, and likely "fatal", as the curly braces will be needed for *something* - such as a loop. Their not being within the PHP tags will mean PHP will simply determine they are *missing*.

> why is the curly brace in second line not completed in the script tag
>   there itself, but placed in the end?

It's in the place it needs to be. The code between where the loop is started, and where it is ended, needs to be included within the loop.

> If this is to continue the loop, why is the script tag closed? Why not
>   to continue in it?

You can break in and out of PHP as desired or required. 
Wordpress is known to follow this pattern, I believe to make it (supposedly) easier to work with the code, rather than one file full of PHP only, it has the HTML separated out.

It's not always a good idea to break in and out of PHP tags, but how and when is "appropriate" is largely down to personal choice.
There are more solid "reasons" (search the site for such questions/debates), but *personally* I prefer to keep it to a minimum.

The actual swapping between PHP and HTML too much can cause it to be less readable than if you just wrote it all in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can also make your code more prettier by using *shortecho* instead of regular `<?php echo`

Usual, standard way to output data

```
<h1><?php echo 'Heading title'; ?></h1>
```

Shorthand way to do the same thing.

```
<h1><?='Heading title'; ?></h1>
```

Both give the same result, You decide which one should fit better for easier reading. Note that `<?=` is not shorttag, as shorttags are not enabled on some servers by default, but something You can rely on at any time.

Regarding this

> Can curly braces in PHP be placed outside the php script tags?

Yes they can, but, that's not php anymore. In 99% that would be some javascript object content. *(joke)

Real answer - no.